# Prove that 4 is not a primitive root modulo n, for $ n \ge 2$

Tags: number-theory

I want to prove that 4 is not a primitive root modulo n, for $ n \ge  2$

I know how to prove it for any **prime** n, but I don't know how to prove it for numbers bigger than 2 which are not primes. Thank you for your help!

Comment: no because I don't talk about primes only

Comment: Similarly you can prove $$4^{\phi(m)/2}\equiv1\pmod m$$

Comment: Primes are enough, for a primitive root of $pn'$ is a primitive root of $p$. But as lab bhattacharjee indicates, there is an easier way.

Comment: @AndréNicolas can you explain please why is it true?

Comment: Use lab  bhattacharjee's comment, it is faster. But about a primitive root of $n=pn'$, if the powers of $g$ cover, modulo $pn'$, all congruence classes relatively prime to $pn'$, they cover all non-zero congruence classes mod $p$.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee could you elaborate how to prove it and how it would help me for m that is not a prime?

Comment: @CnR, What is the order of $a\pmod m,$ if $a$ is a primitive root $\pmod m$